# flutter ListView with Flex for scrollable and responsive page

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to create a page which is scrollable (by using ListView) and support responsive (by using Flex, it will switch from Row to Column when screen's width is small). It works but i am curious that why it requires to set container's height. Anyone can help to explain or give me proper solution?

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isScreenWide = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width >= 800;

    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 400, // need this line to make it works
          color: Colors.blue[100],

          child: Flex(
            direction: isScreenWide ? Axis.horizontal : Axis.vertical,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: const Text("1")),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: const Text("2")),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several details but I will try to explain them to you.

The default ListView has a vertical scrollDirection, it is a requirement for ListView that its children have a size other than infinity in terms of the scroll direction, which is why you have to set the height. That's why you had to put a size on the height of the container.

ListView vertical scrollDirection has infinite height and Flex when it is in a column has infinite height, this is a conflict.

I think this would be the best way to do it:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isScreenWide = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width >= 800;

    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
      scrollDirection: isScreenWide ? Axis.horizontal : Axis.vertical,
      children: [
        Flex(
          direction: isScreenWide ? Axis.horizontal : Axis.vertical,
          children: [
            Container(
                color: Colors.blue[100],
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(100),
                  child: Text("1"),
                )),
            Container(
                color: Colors.blue[200],
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(100),
                  child: Text("2"),
                )),
            Container(
                color: Colors.blue[300],
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(100),
                  child: Text("3"),
                )),
            Container(
                color: Colors.blue[400],
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(100),
                  child: Text("4"),
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: it works. thanks for the solution. I also need to have it to be expended to full width of screen. so i update your code to set the width of containers. 

`Container(width: isScreenWide? MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width / 4: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width,`